# Two persistance units and "Could not resolve a persistence unit corresponding to the persistence-context-ref-name" error

Tags: java, spring, jpa, glassfish

I'm writing spring/JPA project and i need to have two persistence units for two data bases. When there is only one - everything fine, but when i add second persistence unit i get following error:

```
2015-06-26 13:19:26.985 [admin-thread-pool-4848(5)] ERROR j.e.s.c.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server - Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method
2015-06-26 13:19:26.985 [admin-thread-pool-4848(5)] ERROR j.e.s.c.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server - Exception while preparing the app
2015-06-26 13:19:26.985 [admin-thread-pool-4848(5)] ERROR j.e.s.c.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server - Could not resolve a persistence unit corresponding to the persistence-context-ref-name [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean/entityManager] in the scope of the module called [Q_Management_2]. Please verify your application.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not resolve a persistence unit corresponding to the persistence-context-ref-name [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean/entityManager] in the scope of the module called [Q_Management_2]. Please verify your application.
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.BundleDescriptor.findReferencedPUViaEMRef(BundleDescriptor.java:694) ~[dol.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.BundleDescriptor.findReferencedPUsViaPCRefs(BundleDescriptor.java:682) ~[dol.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.WebBundleDescriptor.findReferencedPUs(WebBundleDescriptor.java:1056) ~[dol.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:186) ~[jpa-connector.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168) ~[jpa-connector.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:871) [kernel.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:410) [kernel.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240) [kernel.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389) [deployment-admin.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348) [kernel.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363) [kernel.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085) [kernel.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95) [kernel.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291) [kernel.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259) [kernel.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:214) [rest-service.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:207) [rest-service.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:148) [rest-service.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60) [jersey-gf-server.jar:1.11.1]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205) [jersey-gf-server.jar:1.11.1]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75) [jersey-gf-server.jar:1.11.1]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288) [jersey-gf-server.jar:1.11.1]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134) [jersey-gf-server.jar:1.11.1]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) [jersey-gf-server.jar:1.11.1]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134) [jersey-gf-server.jar:1.11.1]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) [jersey-gf-server.jar:1.11.1]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108) [jersey-gf-server.jar:1.11.1]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) [jersey-gf-server.jar:1.11.1]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84) [jersey-gf-server.jar:1.11.1]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469) [jersey-gf-server.jar:1.11.1]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400) [jersey-gf-server.jar:1.11.1]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349) [jersey-gf-server.jar:1.11.1]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339) [jersey-gf-server.jar:1.11.1]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer._service(GrizzlyContainer.java:182) [jersey-grizzly.jar:1.11.1]
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer.service(GrizzlyContainer.java:147) [jersey-grizzly.jar:1.11.1]
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:148) [rest-service.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179) [grizzly-utils.jar:1.9.50]
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117) [kernel.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354) [kernel.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195) [kernel.jar:3.1.2.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860) [grizzly-http.jar:1.9.50]
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757) [grizzly-http.jar:1.9.50]
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056) [grizzly-http.jar:1.9.50]
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229) [grizzly-http.jar:1.9.50]
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137) [grizzly-framework.jar:1.9.50]
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104) [grizzly-framework.jar:1.9.50]
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90) [grizzly-framework.jar:1.9.50]
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79) [grizzly-http.jar:1.9.50]
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54) [grizzly-framework.jar:1.9.50]
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59) [grizzly-framework.jar:1.9.50]
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71) [grizzly-framework.jar:1.9.50]
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532) [grizzly-utils.jar:1.9.50]
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513) [grizzly-utils.jar:1.9.50]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_67]
2015-06-26 13:19:27.173 [admin-thread-pool-4848(5)] ERROR j.e.s.t.a.o.g.deployment.admin - Exception while preparing the app : Could not resolve a persistence unit corresponding to the persistence-context-ref-name [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean/entityManager] in the scope of the module called [Q_Management_2]. Please verify your application.
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="qp_centralPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/CentralPool</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.0.68:1433" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="qp_central" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="qp_central" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="SQLServerDialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
                  value="org.hibernate.transaction.SunONETransactionManagerLookup"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect_resolvers" value="com.qmatic.qp.dialect.UnicodeSQLServer2008DialectResolver" />
        <property name="hibernate.HibernateException" value="org.hibernate.HibernateException"    />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="qp_statPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/StatPool</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.0.68:1433" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="stat" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="stat" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="SQLServerDialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
                  value="org.hibernate.transaction.SunONETransactionManagerLookup" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect_resolvers" value="com.qmatic.qp.dialect.UnicodeSQLServer2008DialectResolver" />
        <property name="hibernate.HibernateException" value="org.hibernate.HibernateException"    />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.qsystems.Repository, com.qsystems.DAL, com.qsystems.controllers" />
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

<bean id="CentralTransactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="CentralEmf" />
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
</bean>

<bean id="StatTransactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="StatEmf" />
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
</bean>

<bean id="jpaDialect"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />

<bean id="CentralEmf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceCentral"/>
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.glassfish.GlassFishLoadTimeWeaver"/>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="qp_centralPU" />
    <property name="persistenceProviderClass" value="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.SunONETransactionManagerLookup</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
</bean>


<bean id="StatEmf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceStat"/>
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.glassfish.GlassFishLoadTimeWeaver"/>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="qp_statPU" />
    <property name="persistenceProviderClass" value="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.SunONETransactionManagerLookup</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSourceCentral" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName"  value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433" />
    <!--<property name="url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.0.68:1433" />-->
    <property name="username" value="qp_central" />
    <property name="password" value="qp_central" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSourceStat" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName"  value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433" />
    <property name="username" value="stat" />
    <property name="password" value="stat" />
</bean>
```

Connection pools:

```
Resource Type: javax.sql.XADataSource
Datasource Classname: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource
```

DAO class:

```
@Repository
@Transactional(value = "CentralTransactionManager")
public class BranchDAO {

    protected EntityManagerFactory emf;
    private EntityManager em;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "qp_centralPU")
    @Qualifier(value = "CentralEmf")
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em)
    {
        this.em = em;
    }

    public Branch getBranchById(long Id)
    {
        return em.find(Branch.class, Id);
    }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: How do you retrieve the `EntityManager` inside your classes? I guess have not specified the PersistenceUnit there...

Comment: Rename your `peristence.xml` to something else and explicitly declare which one to use for the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactory`. The existence of a `persistence.xml` triggers GlassFish to scan for `@PersistenceUnit` and `@PersistenceContext` annotations and treat the application like an EJB3 application.

Comment: @unwichtich,`public class BranchGroupDAO {

    protected EntityManagerFactory emf;
    private EntityManager em;

    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "qp_centralPU")
    @Qualifier(value = "CentralEmf")
    public void setEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        this.emf = emf;
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    public List<BranchGroup> getAllBranchGroups() {
        List<BranchGroup> brList = null;
        brList = em.createQuery("SELECT b FROM BranchGroup b").getResultList();
        return brList;
    }
}
`

Comment: I'd advise to declare persistence xml location for your beans `CentralEmf` and `StatEmf`. Do ti like this `<property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml" />`. And [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4423260/548601) may be also helpful.

Comment: Hello guys, i tried everything you suggest, but nothing helps.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same error in a `JPA`+`Spring`+`Glassfish` project with two persistent units.

There were two hints which in conjunction led to a success:

The first one is [this](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-89), and second one is [this](http://javaee.ch/2012/11/02/198/).