# Using same jdbcTemplate for two different schemas

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have 2 datasources say `dataSourceA` and `dataSourceB` but based upon few calculations, I need to execute the same query in different schemas. Also, it is going to be executed in  either of the schemas.

so, at DAO layer , I have one `setDataSource()` method which is `@autowired` to the `dataSourceA`, thus,returning the JDBCTemplate with former DataSource. How can I implement the `dataSourceB` changes using the same JDBCTemplate as it will be difficult to change at every DAO layer as entire application change will be required.

Comment: why don't you use schema name in your queries instead of define schema name in your datasource?

Comment: Go through this link. Not having exact answer but you may get some idea.
http://zetcode.com/articles/springbootqualifier/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could you inject both datasources and select the datasource inside your method according to your logic:

```
public class SomeDaoImpl implements SomeDao {
    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateA;
    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateB;

    @Autowired
    public SomeDaoImpl(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateA, JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateB) {
        // injecting both JdbcTemplate instances
        this.jdbcTemplateA = jdbcTemplateA;
        this.jdbcTemplateB = jdbcTemplateB;
    }

    public void businessLogicMethod(...) {
        // choosing the actual template to be used according to your logic
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = chooseTemplate(...);
        // now using the template to execute a query
        jdbcTemplate.execute(...);
    }
}
```

Another option would be to instantiate two `SomeDaoImpl` instances and inject one `JdbcTemplate` into each of them, and select the DAO instance in your service layer.

But both these solutions have a flaw: transaction is usually initiated in the service layer (with an interceptor, for example), and it has no idea that you are going to route your requests to another datasource; so it could happen that a transaction starts on one datasource, but the query is executed on another one.

So the clearest solution would be to go one level up and instantiate 2 services, in each of them DAOs with different `JdbcTemplate` instances. Of course, 2 transaction managers will have to be configured and carefully wired (for example, via `@Transactional("transactionManagerA")`). More information on this here [Spring - Is it possible to use multiple transaction managers in the same application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423125/spring-is-it-possible-to-use-multiple-transaction-managers-in-the-same-applica)