# spring @Transactional with jdbcTemplate in Java

Tags: java, spring, oracle, transactions

I am learning spring and got stuck with this below issue. Searched some of the solution but didnt help much so Need some help

I am trying to read and write data from two different database (DB2 and Oracle).
I would like to use Spring @Transactional annotation and want to create Transaction manager and jdbcTemplate with two different database.

I want to use both **Transaction manager** and **jdbcTemplate** for DB2 and Oracle and from application I want to do the db operation using jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate().

can you please tell if it's possible to create separate **Transaction manager** and **jdbcTemplate** for DB2 and Oracle ?

Comment: @Rajarshi Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423125/spring-is-it-possible-to-use-multiple-transaction-managers-in-the-same-applica

Comment: @JB Nizet  I already checked the link provided , but it's not saying how to use both Transaction manager and jdbcTemplate in same scenario.

Comment: @Rajarshi I believe you should clarify exactly what you want to do *with some code*. Post the code you *wish* you could use, and state clearly why it does not work.