# TransactionRequiredException in a method that is already annotated with @Transactional

Tags: jsf-2, cdi

```
public void postPessoa() {
    savePessoa();
    initializePessoa();
}

@Transactional(rollbackOn = {Exception.class})
public void savePessoa() {
    pessoa = getEntityManager().merge(pessoa);
}
```

If I call `postPessoa()` I got `TransactionRequiredException` in `merge()`, but if I call `savePessoa()` directly from JSF it works, and I didn't understand why this behavior.

**JSF:**

```
<p:commandButton id="btnSalvar" value="Salvar" action="#{pessoasController.savePessoa}"/>

<p:commandButton id="btnSalvar" value="Salvar" action="#{pessoasController.postPessoa}"/>
```

Comment: This is effectively not a JSF question. Same would have happend if you would have created a good unittest

Comment: Probably, but I want to understand why calling annotated method directly from jsf change the behavior of Transactional annotation.

Comment: It is not about calling it directly from jsf it is about calling it directly period. See the answer. Btw are you using spring or cdi? Answer is right both for spring and cdi

Comment: I understand. I'm using CDI, but I'll be honest I'm asking because I don't know if my error is in jsf calling, in transactional or in my jpa control. I search a lot before ask here...

Comment: That is why I mentioned a unit test. Yo can then exclude things. JSF in this case

Comment: and the answer IS the answer to your question. Maybe not to your other problem but it is to this one

Comment: I solved... but I think I just did a "hack"... <p:commandButton value="Salvar" action="#{pessoasController.initializePessoa}">
                        <f:actionListener binding="#{pessoasController.savePessoa(false)}"  /></p:commandButton> But I'm almost sure that isn't the best practice. So actionListener executes first the method with transaction and action the other one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add

```
@Transactional
```

...on class level OR on `postPessoa()`, too.

from [spring-doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-annotations):

> In proxy mode (**which is the default**), **only external method calls**
>   coming in through the proxy are intercepted. **This means that
>   self-invocation, in effect, a method within the target object calling
>   another method of the target object, will not lead to an actual
>   transaction at runtime** even if the invoked method is marked with
>   @Transactional. Also, the proxy must be fully initialized to provide
>   the expected behaviour so you should not rely on this feature in your
>   initialization code, i.e. @PostConstruct.

Comment: but it is not propagated, when "calling this" ...that's why OR

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn That is what Xerx593 stated. Thing is that if it is on a method it has to be a method that is called from outside the bean

Comment: Ah ha, I was oversighted. His method was called within a class. Nice catch

Comment: @xerx593 but if I add Transactional in postPessoa(), the method initializePessoa() will be in the same transaction context, and that isn't what I want or am I wrong?

Comment: aha!? (a second tx-context!?) you want to mix? (please explain ...sounds [tough..impossible])

Comment: ...no, it's easy! with [2 tx-managers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4423260/592355), you must mix/call them from "another bean" (a controller or something)!

Comment: thanks @xerx593, but I think that isn't what I need. I get into this issue after trying to initialize Lazy entities after a merge. When I call postPessoa() I want to merge and call initializePessoa() which is responsible to fetch all the lazy objects, but if I use initializePessoa() in a transaction context setListX() give me a error because hibernate identify as a change in entity. Maybe my problem isn't in transactional, but I'm really in doubt.